# Print out even number

Tags: c++

I just want to ask your help here. I am new beginner in c++ programming. How to print out the even number in range 100 - 200. I tried write some code and it didn't work out. Here is my code. I hope, someone here can help me. Will appreciate that so much. Thanks.

```
include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i;
    for (i= 100; i<= 200; i += 2){
        print i;
    }
}
```

Comment: In any programming language, start with [Hello World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world), and [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), before you try anything else.

Comment: Well, this code does the job, except for the part with the printing. You should look at printf() function or using std::cout

Comment: This isn't C either. C doesn't have a `void main()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Well, pretty simple:

```
#include <iostream> // This is the C++ I/O header, has basic functions like output an input.

int main(){ // the main function is generally an int, not a void.
   for(int i = 100; i <= 200; i+=2){ // for loop to advance by 2.
       std::cout << i << std::endl; // print out the number and go to next line, std:: is a prefix used for functions in the std namespace.
   } // End for loop
   return 0; // Return int function
} // Close the int function, end of program
```

you were using C libraries, not C++ ones, as well as no function that is called `print` in C++, nor `C`. Also there is no void main function, use `int main()` instead. finally, you need to have `std::` in front of `cout` and `endl` as these lie in the `std` namespace.

Comment: You should use `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

Comment: In fact, you *must* qualify the references with the `std` namespace in order for the code to compile.

Comment: Most likely you don't need `std::endl` at each iteration either.

Comment: @scai Why? I'm interested too as I sometimes see examples with `std::cout` but don't understand why - I've never come across problems just using `cout`

Comment: @duncan12 There is no "just `cout`". `cout` is defined in the `std` namespace. The only way it will work without fully qualifying the namespace reference is if you've written `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code, which is [generally considered bad form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c), especially in headers.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I've always just used `using namespace std;` and `cout`, `cin` etc. Not 100% convinced though as I'm not using two namespaces or anything..

Comment: I'd suggest to declare `i` in the `for` loop. Having local iterators is one of the most convenient features of C++ (and C99).

Comment: @Mehrwolf oh, okay, this is what I do, since i first learned C89.

Comment: I did, I just kept that convention. There is nothing wrong with it, and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good....Only the printing part needs to be changed

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
    for (int i= 100; i<= 200; i += 2){
      printf("%d",i);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: ...and the part where he uses `void main()`, which doesn't exist in either C or C++. The `main` method always returns an `int`.

Comment: @CodyGray True.... But even with a void main....You would get a warning.... The code would work fine

Comment: so is there any difference when use void main?

Comment: The code would not work fine, unless your compiler supported a void return type on main as an extension.  GCC does not.  It doesn't just give a warning, it gives an error.

Comment: `return 0` is in bad scope. It will just print 100 and exit.

Comment: @MayankKhandelwal, the output is return 100.

Comment: @PatrickWills.... I guess pawel is right... it would depend on the compiler.... My compiler was passing it..... But i guess int main is a must then

Comment: Yes, getting the return type of the `main` method wrong invokes undefined behavior. That means what actually happens depends on your implementation. It could do anything it wanted. GCC just shakes its head at you, some older compilers provided an extension that would always return 0 to the OS if `main` returned `void`. That doesn't mean it wasn't wrong all along. As usual with undefined behavior, you shouldn't rely on it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i= 100; i<= 200; i += 2){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to flush the output stream at each line.

Comment: Oh oops deleted my prev. comment because it was answered elsewhere then you replied. But I've always done `using namespace std;` at the top then just `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help!

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int count = 100; count <= 200; count += 2)
    {
        cout << count << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```